# Return function returning to main instead of caller

Tags: arrays, recursion, parameters, return, program-entry-point

just wondering...

```
void mazeTraversal(char maze[12][12], int x, int y)
{
if (maze[x + 1][y] == '.')
    mazeTraversal(maze, ++x, y);
if (maze[x][y + 1] == '.')
    mazeTraversal(maze, x, ++y);
if (maze[x - 1][y] == '.')
    mazeTraversal(maze, --x, y);
if (maze[x][y - 1] == '.')
    mazeTraversal(maze, x, --y);
   return;
}
```

when i hit a dead end, should i revert to the previous instance of the call, instead of going straight back to the main function? If I have something wrong please tell me.

Comment: "should i revert to the previous instance of the call" What do you mean?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @user2646981 What compile flags are you using? Could it be that you're getting bit by tail recursion optimizations? (Also, tag this as C if you're using C)

Comment: @DennisMeng are they on by default in gcc? If not, then I doubt it. I only have debug and assembly output options on..

Comment: In that case, what do you see in the assembly? If it's doing some unexpected optimization, that'd be one way to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following addresses using a return value to capture "correct path" information as well as providing a [*base case* condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29). However, another *crucial problem* with the original code is the use of `++/--` which cause *side effects* upon the respective variables. The code below eschews these operators for that reason.

---

The primary way to do this is to return a value - say, *true* if this path led to and end or *false* otherwise.

A very primitive conversion would then look like the following. Note the addition of the base case - this means that we can stop recursing. True is returned so that previous caller(s) also know they can stop looking and the function stack will quickly be unwound back to "main".

```
bool mazeTraversal(char maze[12][12], int x, int y) {
  // This is the BASE CASE and means WE ARE DONE LOOKING
  if (maze[x][y] == 'X') return true; // found end!

  if (maze[x + 1][y] == '.')
    if (mazeTraversal(maze, x + 1, y)) return true;

  if (maze[x][y + 1] == '.')
     if (mazeTraversal(maze, x, y + 1)) return true;

  if (maze[x - 1][y] == '.')
     if (mazeTraversal(maze, x - 1, y)) return true;

  if (maze[x][y - 1] == '.')
     if (mazeTraversal(maze, x, y - 1)) return true;

  return false; // didn't find any valid path from here
}
```

Note that *I removed `++/--` to avoid strange side-effects*.

However, we can do better and clean up the code some. The crucial difference is each recursive calls checks the *current location* - instead of the location of its neighbors.

```
bool mazeTraversal(char maze[12][12], int x, int y) {
  if (maze[x][y] == 'X')
    return true; // found end!

  if (maze[x][y] == '.') {
    // we are still on a path - see where exploration leads!
    if (mazeTraversal(maze, x + 1, y)) return true;
    if (mazeTraversal(maze, x, y + 1)) return true;
    if (mazeTraversal(maze, x - 1, y)) return true;
    if (mazeTraversal(maze, x, y - 1)) return true;
  }

  // Didn't find any valid path from here -
  // maybe "here" is a wall!
  return false;
}
```

Ultimately you'd likely want to do something else on the found path (i.e. where it reads "return true") such as record the current position.

Also note that, depending on the language, the `if (mazeTraversal..) return true` stuff can also be "cleaned up". In C, consider using a *short-circuiting* `||` operator. Then we can shorten the end case to something like:

```
int leadsToEnd =
       (maze[x][y] == 'X')      // at end
    || (maze[x][y] == '.')      // or not end ..
       && (mazeTraversal(maze, x + 1, y)   // but may lead to end
           || mazeTraversal(maze, x, y + 1)
           || mazeTraversal(maze, x - 1, y) 
           || mazeTraversal(maze, x, y - 1));
```

And thus the entire function effectively becomes `return leadsToEnd` (substituting the above expression as desired). Of course, you'll have to decided which approach - the latter example is arguably overly clever - or hybrid of such makes most sense to you.

Comment: That is the most convoluted approach, but it works. Brilliant...thank you so much. However, im still confused as to why my method didn't work...I know void types are well, not actual values, but i would assume a void function would still return like a normal function....

Comment: thank you...nonetheless, just for educational purposes...can you explain why my initial approach didnt work?

Comment: i did copy your approach (substituting the bool with int) and it works fantastic. however, still have questions: 1)i didn't include a base case, i understand, but when saying return, shouldn't it revert to the caller function regardless? Say i went with the first conditional statement, called the function and then found it was a ead end. when i get to the return statement in that called function, shouldn't it go back to the caller, instead of returning to main? 2) what side effects can incrementors and decrementors cause?

Comment: I've updated the answer some. Also see the link to the wikipedia recursion article, and see the *base case*.

Comment: wow..i've just realized. incrementors change the variable permanently. i might have well just added x = x + 1 there. such a small mistake ...at least now my original code works (i added a base case to when it reaches the exit opint of the maze). Thank you for mentioning that mistake

Comment: The call stack works correctly - it will never "unwind past" a function call. However, the use of `++/--` might have led to misreading what was occurring. `x++` returns the current value of x and then *increments* `x`. This means that the next time `x` is used it will have an incorrect value.

Comment: @user2646981 Glad you have everything working. Enjoy class :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have it now, when you hit a dead-end, you just return.  That is correct, as you will back up to the previous call and then select the next path.  When you have traversed all the possible paths, your top-level call will return.

Comment: well you see, it actually reverts back to the main: that is what baffles me. I also assumed that it would stack up like one would logically assume recursion does, but...its almost as is the return is a goto main... P.S.: C standard